# Read Existing Avro File and Send to Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, streaming, avro

I have an existing Avro File with the schema. I need to send the file to Producer.

Following is the code i have written.

```
public class ProducerDataSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String topic = "my-topic";

        Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
        Schema schema = parser.parse(AvroSchemaDefinitionLoader.fromFile("encounter.avsc").get());

            File file = new File("/home/hello.avro");
        try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
        DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(datumWriter);
        dataFileWriter.create(schema, outputStream);
        dataFileWriter.appendTo(file);
        dataFileWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Here comes the data: " + outputStream);



        // Start KAFKA publishing

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> messageProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(props);
        ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> producerRecord = null;
        producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>("m-topic","1",outputStream.toByteArray());
        messageProducer.send(producerRecord);
        messageProducer.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in sending to kafka");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }
}
```

As soon as I execute this, I get the error:

```
Error in sending to kafka org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: already open
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.assertNotOpen(DataFileWriter.java:85) 
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.appendTo(DataFileWriter.java:203)
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.appendTo(DataFileWriter.java:193)
at ProducerDataSample.main(ProducerDataSample.java:51)
```

Any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to read the data from the avro file and serialize it to bytes array

Something like below snippet

```
        final Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("sample.avsc"));            
        File file ="sample.avro"

        //read the avro file to GenericRecord
        final GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> genericDatumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
        final DataFileReader<GenericRecord> genericRecords = new DataFileReader<>(file, genericDatumReader);

        //serialize GenericRecords
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);

        Encoder binaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);

        while (genericRecords.hasNext()) {
            writer.write(genericRecords.next(), binaryEncoder);
        }
        binaryEncoder.flush();
        out.close();
       //send out.toByteArray() to kakfa
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answer should look like this to send individual records as Kafka events.

Note: It should be possible to get the schema directly from the Avro file rather than have a separate AVSC file. [Following code in the Avro project](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/branch-1.8/lang/java/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/tool/DataFileGetSchemaTool.java#L47-L50)

```
final Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("sample.avsc"));            
File file = new File("sample.avro");

//read the avro file to GenericRecord
final GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> genericDatumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
final DataFileReader<GenericRecord> genericRecords = new DataFileReader<>(file, genericDatumReader);

DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);

while (genericRecords.hasNext()) {
    //serialize GenericRecords
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Encoder binaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
    writer.write(genericRecords.next(), binaryEncoder);
    binaryEncoder.flush();
    out.close();

    // TODO: send out.toByteArray() to kafka
}

// TODO: kafkaProducer.flush();
```

Comment: Isn't this too much trouble? You read records from the file, deserialize them into GenericRecord's and then serialize them and send them to Kafka. Wouldn't it be possible to just read the serialized record into a byte array and send that to Kafka?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to deliniate the byte arrays within the file outside of the `GenericDatumReader`. Similarly, you would want the schema with the record when sending, not just the raw value.

Comment: Yep, checked the spec and the actual code that reads the file. While the data blocks are nicely separated, the raw data of the individual records are simply concatenated within the block, and there is no way to separate them without decoding the data using the schema.

Comment: By the way, reading the code taught me that the schema passed to the `GenericDatumReader(Schema)`constructor is not the schema of the file, but the target schema, which may be a different version of the schema used for writing the file. Not only does the code deserialize the record, it also maps it to a potential new version of the schema. If you want to use the schema of the file as target, you can use the `GenericDatumReader()` constructor. You can obtain the schema of the file using `GenericDatumReader.getSchema()` after opening the file.