# Avro Serialization/Deserialization to/from Kafka Topic

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro

I am trying to create a generic utility which would read avro files from Kafka topic and write avro files to the topic in Java.
I could not find much documentation on the same.
Appreciate any working code.

Comment: It'd be useful to see what you've tried so far and what issues you are having. Otherwise, the question is a little vague

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you saw this question? [Read Existing Avro File and Send to Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398519/read-existing-avro-file-and-send-to-kafka)

---

You typically do not have "files" in Kafka... There's plenty of documentation around Avro about how to read/write files, but Kafka deals with singular records as just `byte[]` objects. Avro provides the `BinaryEncoder` class to get records to byte arrays

If you are using Kafka with Avro, you're often going to be using the Confluent Schema Registry. This makes each Kafka message not require a fully encoded Avro schema, but rather just a numeric reference id with the binary data

You can find their quickstart here

https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/index.html

And Github example repo here

https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.2.1-post/clients/avro/README.md

---

If you're not using the Schema Registry, you must write your own serializers. Here's an example using plain Kafka API for the Producer and Spark for the consumer via the Bijection library

http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/03/04/kafka-spark-avro-producing-and-consuming-avro-messages.html

Note that Spark already has a package for dealing with Avro. In theory, you could directly use it to read Avro files as a Dataframe and write them to a Kafka topic.

Spark isn't necessary at all. Bijection could be used by a Kafka Consumer or Deserializer interface as well

Comment: Created Producer and Consumer class(using schemaregistry).When I am using io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer,it is sometime throwing error saying org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition partiton_1-6 at offset 15047 <Full error i have added in answer section>

Comment: `Unknown magic byte` means **some** event is not actually Avro. There is no easy way to read these events, so you just have to catch the exception and skip them or send them to a differernt "dead-letter" topic

Comment: You could look at the event on the CLI with `kafka-console-consumer --topic partiton_1 --partition 6 --offset 15047 --max-messages=1`